# define if with cond doesn't work

Tags: scheme, racket

I try to implement a "special-if" that suppose to behave like regular "if" with cond. Here's the code:

```
(define (special-if pre act alt)
  (cond (pre act)
        (else alt)))
```

To test if this works, I wrote a factorial function with this "special-if":

```
(define (factorial n)
       (special-if (= n 1)
           1
           (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
```

However, when I evaluate (factorial 3), it runs forever. Seems the predicate part `(= n 1)` was never evaluated. Can anyone tell me why this won't work? Thanks.

Comment: Try using the stepper and see what happens (if you're using DrRacket)

Comment: Arguments are evaluated before being passed to functions. So when `new-if` both the `act` and `alt` arguments are evaluated. Thus your infinite recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your special `if` is doomed to fail, I'm afraid. Remember: `if` is an special form with different evaluation rules (and `cond` is a macro implemented using `if`), that's why an expression like this runs fine even though it has a division by zero:

```
(if true 'ok (/ 1 0))
=> 'ok
```

... whereas your `special-if` will raise an error, because it's using the normal evaluation rules that apply for procedures, meaning that all its arguments get evaluated *before* executing the procedure:

```
(special-if true 'ok (/ 1 0))
=> /: division by zero
```

Now you see why your code fails: at the bottom of the recursion when `n` is `1` *both* the consequent and the alternative will execute!

```
(special-if (= 1 1)
    1                          ; this expression is evaluated
    (* 1 (factorial (- 1 1)))) ; and this expression too!
```

... And `factorial` will happily continue to execute with values `0`, `-1`, `-2` and so on, leading to an infinite loop. Bottom line: you *have to* use an existing special form (or define a new macro) for implementing conditional behavior, a user-defined standard procedure simply won't work here.

Comment: There is an exercise from SICP about this very problem :|

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

You've heard *why* your `special-if` doesn't work, but you accepted an answer that doesn't tell you how to make it work:

```
(define-syntax special-if 
  (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ pre act alt)
       (cond (pre act)
             (else alt)))))
```

That defines a macro, which is expanded at compile time. Every time the compiler sees something that matches this pattern and begins with `special-if`, it gets replaced with the template shown. As a result, `pre`, `act`, and `alt` don't get evaluated until your `special-if` form gets turned into a `cond` form.

Understanding how macros work is difficult using Scheme, because Scheme does its damnedest to hide what's really going on. If you were using Common Lisp, the macro would be a simple function that takes snippets of uncompiled code (in the form of lists, symbols, strings, and numbers) as arguments, and returns uncompiled code as its value. In Common Lisp, `special-if` would just return a list:

```
(defmacro special-if (pre act alt)
   (list 'cond (list pre act)
               (list t alt)))
```

Scheme macros work the same way, except the lists, symbols, etc. are wrapped in "syntax objects" that also contain lexical information, and instead of using list
operators such as `car` and `cdr`, Scheme and Racket provide a pattern-matching and template engine that delves into the syntax objects and handles the extra data (but doesn't allow you to handle any of it directly).

Comment: Thanks for the advanced solution!